# editingAccessoryType not showing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a table view in one of my viewcontrollers which gets set to edit mode using:

`self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;`

I'm also setting the cell's editingAccessoryType to the appropriate UITableViewCellAccessoryType:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  }
  NSString *cellLabel = [cellDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  NSString *cellData = [movieDictionary objectForKey:cellLabel];
  cell.textLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@", cellLabel, cellData];
  cell.editingAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
  cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
  return cell;
}
```

within `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. However, when I tap the Edit button, the accessories don't show. The table is being set to edit mode (`setEditing` is being called). Does anyone know what I'm missing out on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you implement the setEditing?

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];

}
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply. Yes, I do implement that method.

Comment: The problem was that I wasn't doing `self.table setEditing...` but `table setEditing...`. Thanks for that! What is the difference between the two?

Comment: I was converting a UITableViewController to a UIViewController with Table View inside it and obviously this is a method required during that transition. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` for the `editingAccessoryType`. <strike>That's not going to work</strike>.

Make sure all the other cell animations are working that you expect during edit.

Also, check if you have overridden `layoutSubviews` in a subclass.

If you cannot resolve this in another way, consider setting `editingAccessoryView` to show what you want to show during editing.